# Extracting the outer-boundary of a set of grid points with some missing grids (holes)

Tags: r

This question is about generalization of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538161/find-the-perimeter-of-a-subset-of-a-near-regular-grid-of-points/28551704?noredirect=1#comment62340906_28551704) question. The mentioned question is working well for the point set with no hole. In the present question I want to get the perimeter (outer boundary) of a subset of a near-regular grid of points where some of the grid point with in the polygon are missing (i.e., polygon with hole).

The sample data set on grids is available [here](https://spaces.hightail.com/space/lY7n0/fi-c047ae46-d139-451f-b71a-104c2c90d269/fv-58222d76-4022-4595-a5bc-e76b4e9663e4/data).

I used the R-code as suggested as an answer in the above mentioned question (with no holes).

The following is the output of using those codes:[image: plot]

Now I want it ignore holes in inside the point set and want to consider the outer boundary of the point set as the required polygon.

Any suggestion!! Thanks.

Comment: Maybe chull() can help https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/chull.html

Comment: @bluefish. In past I used chulll. But it is missing some of the boundary points as the points are not equispaced. So it is not useful in this case.

Comment: Hmm I see the problem. The holes are homologous to squares and so my algorithm from the other question recognises them as boundaries. Now I'm not sure if the solution is to first fill the holes and then use my previous solution, or to run on the data with holes and then figure out which of the "boundaries" is the true boundary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This slight variant on my previous code works if there's holes by finding all the loops and taking only the one with the largest X coordinate, which must be the outside loop. Unless the loops touch... Strictly perhaps it should take the loop with the largest area... Note also the need to use X and Y in one of the functions because of a bug (I've reported) in the igraph package.

```
perimeterGrid <- function(pts, maxdist=6000, mindist=1){
    g = edgeP(makegrid(pts, maxdist=maxdist, mindist=mindist))

    ## there might be holes. Find the loop with the largest X coordinate.
    parts = components(g)
    outer = which.max(tapply(V(g)$x, parts$membership, function(x){max(x)}))

    g = induced_subgraph(g, which(parts$membership==outer))

    loop = graph.dfs(minimum.spanning.tree(g),1)$order
    cbind(V(g)$x, V(g)$y)[loop,]
}

# haversine distance matrix
dmat <- function(pts){
    n=nrow(pts)
    do.call(rbind,lapply(1:n,function(i){distHaversine(pts[i,],pts)}))
}

# make the grid cells given a maxdist (and a mindist to stop self-self edges)    
makegrid <- function(pts, maxdist=6000,  mindist=1){
    dists = dmat(pts)
    g = graph.adjacency(dists<maxdist & dists>mindist,
        mode="undirected")
    ## use X and Y here not x and y due to igraph bug
    ## these get copied to the output later...
    V(g)$X=pts[,1]
    V(g)$Y=pts[,2]

    g
}

# clever function that does the grid edge count etc
edgeP <- function(g){
    # find all the simple squares
    square=graph.ring(4)
    subs = graph.get.subisomorphisms.vf2(g,square)
    # expand all the edges
    subs = do.call(rbind, lapply(subs, function(s){
        rbind(s[1:2], s[2:3], s[3:4], s[c(4,1)])
    }))
    # make new graph of the edges of all the squares
    e = graph.edgelist(subs,directed=FALSE)
    # add the weight as the edge count
    E(e)$weight=count.multiple(e)

    # copy the coords from the source back
    V(e)$x=V(g)$X
    V(e)$y=V(g)$Y

    # remove multiple edges
    e=simplify(e)

    # internal edges now have weight 256.
    e = e - edges(which(E(e)$weight==256))
    # internal nodes how have degree 0
    e = e - vertices(degree(e)==0)
    return(e)
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem and also  this code is working with igraph 1.0.1.   I gratefully appreciate your help. Thank you very much.